# Error encountered when creating a post in a blog page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a blog page where users can create posts. Upon clicking the "Create Post" button, the post is successfully added to the database and displayed on the blog. However, I am encountering an error during this process. The page turns red and I receive an error message saying:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

To create a post, I have implemented the following steps:

On the server-side (index.js), I have created routes for registering, logging in, and creating posts. I have also defined a middleware for file upload using `multer`.
On the client-side, I have an `IndexPage` component that fetches and displays the posts.
I have a `CreatePost` component where users can enter the post details, including a file upload using `ReactQuill` and the input type "file".

I expected that upon creating a post, it would be successfully added to the database and displayed on the blog without any errors. However, the encountered error turns the page red and prevents a smooth experience.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to identify and fix the error in order to successfully create a post without encountering any issues. Thank you in advance for your help.

**Index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./models/User');
const Post = require('./models/Post');
const cors = require('cors');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const app = express();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const uploadMiddleware = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
const fs = require('fs');

const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const secret = 'asdfe45we45w345wegw345werjktjwertkj';

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000' }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://g00366442:Ajstar11@cluster0.fc4rsgr.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority');

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const userDoc = await User.create({
      username,
      password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt),
    });
    res.json(userDoc);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(400).json(e);
  }
});

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const userDoc = await User.findOne({ username });
  const passOk = bcrypt.compareSync(password, userDoc.password);
  if (passOk) {
    // logged in
    jwt.sign({ username, id: userDoc._id }, secret, {}, (err, token) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.cookie('token', token).json({
        id: userDoc._id,
        username,
      });
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400).json('wrong credentials');
  }
});

app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;
  jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, (err, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(info);
  });
});

app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('token', '').json('ok');
});

app.post('/post', uploadMiddleware.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  const { originalname, path } = req.file;
  const parts = originalname.split('.');
  const ext = parts[parts.length - 1];
  const newPath = path + '.' + ext;
  fs.renameSync(path, newPath);

  const { token } = req.cookies;
  jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const { title, summary, content } = req.body;
    const postDoc = await Post.create({
      title,
      summary,
      content,
      cover: newPath,
      author: info.id,
    });
    res.json(postDoc);
  });
});

app.get('/post', async (req, res) => {
  res.json(await Post.find());
});

app.listen(4000);
```

**IndexPage.js**

```
import Post from "../Post";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/post').then(response => {
      response.json().then(posts => {
        setPosts(posts);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {posts.length > 0 && posts.map(post => (
        <Post key={post.id} {...post} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

**CreatePost.js**

```
import React, { useState, Navigate } from "react";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";

const modules = {
  toolbar: [
    [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
    ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
    [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }, { indent: "-1" }],
    ["link", "image"],
    ["clean"]
  ]
};

const formats = [
  'header',
  'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote',
  'list', 'bullet', 'indent',
  'link', 'image'
];

export default function CreatePost() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [summary, setSummary] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [files, setFiles] = useState("");
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  async function createNewPost(ev) {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.set('title', title);
    data.set('summary', summary);
    data.set('content', content);
    data.set('file', files[0]);
    ev.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/post', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      credentials: 'include',
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      setRedirect(true);
    }
  }

  if (redirect) {
    return <Navigate to={'/'} />;
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={createNewPost}>
      <input
        type="title"
        placeholder={'Title'}
        value={title}
        onChange={ev => setTitle(ev.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="summary"
        placeholder={'Summary'}
        value={summary}
        onChange={ev => setSummary(ev.target.value)}
      />
      <input type="file" onChange={ev => setFiles(ev.target.files)} />

      <ReactQuill
        value={content}
        onChange={value => setContent(value)}
        modules={modules}
        formats={formats}
        theme="snow"
      />

      <button type="submit">Create Post</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

**Post.js**

```
import { formatISO9075 } from "date-fns";

export default function Post({title, summary, cover, content, createdAt}) {
  
  return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="image">
        <img src="https://images.barrons.com/im-789925?width=639&size=1.5" alt="" />
      </div>

      <div className="texts">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p className="info">
          <a className="author">David Paszko </a>
          <time>{formatISO9075(new Date(createdAt))}</time>
        </p>
        <p className="summary">{summary}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Give us your Post.js file. It seems like it was exported or imported incorrectly.

Comment: Appologies, your Post.js component on your client side, not the schema on your server side. (import Post from "../Post";) in your IndexPage.js file

Comment: ok will get it now

Comment: Well, the issue is that you are importing an invalid file to your project. It looks like you are importing the Post.js file correctly, but you might have made a mistake in your path (../Post.js). Double check that the paths of imports are correctly added. You can try to console.log(Post) just below the import statement and see if it is undefined. If it is, your path is not correct.